# как правильно добавить html на странице корзины

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всем доброго дня.
Хочу сделать класс для доставки на woocommerce.
Вроде что то получилось. Но нужно добавить на странице корзины, рядом с доставкой, ссылку на карту для выбора адреса. Создал js  и css  файлы и подключил с помощью функции delivery_include_frontend_js

```
    function delivery_include_frontend_js()
    {
        if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-autocomplete", array('jquery','jquery-ui-core'));
            wp_enqueue_script('cds_delivery_script', DELIVERY_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'assets/js/delivery.js', array('jquery' ), '1.0');
            wp_enqueue_style('cds_delivery_style', DELIVERY_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'assets/css/delivery.css');
        }
    }
```

и просто вызываю эту функцию в init()

```
        $this->delivery_include_frontend_js();
```

Работает при загрузки страницы, но когда я выбираю другую доставку то исчезает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как правильно добавить html на странице корзины?

---

[image: мне нужно сделать примерно так, как у СДЭК-а]

мне нужно сделать примерно так, как у СДЭК-а

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для страниц cart и checkout есть специальный набор хуков

Cart page

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-cart-page/

Checkout page

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/

Соответственно добавлять на страницы cart или checkout нужно через них

Например, для страницы checkout добавить текст перед формой (вставить в плагин или в тему functions.php)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'show_checkout_hello', 5 );

function show_checkout_hello() {
  echo '<h2>Hello there!</h2>';
}
```

Для вывода описания в зависимости от способы доставки используйте [woocommerce_after_shipping_rate](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_after_shipping_rate)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_after_shipping_rate', 20, 2 );
function action_after_shipping_rate ( $method, $index ) {
    // Targeting checkout page only:
    if( is_cart() ) return; // Exit on cart page

    if( 'flat_rate:1' === $method->id ) {
        echo __("<p>Description</p>");
    }
}
```

где вместо "flat_rate:1" укажите айди вашего метода доставки

Comment: а как добавить текст или html к своему доставку?

Comment: @vardanmakhsudyanlean-itru не понимаю. "к своему доставку" ?

Comment: Valerii Vasiliev, мне нужно сделать примерно так, как у СДЭК-а

Comment: @vardan изменил ответ. последняя часть ответа про хук woocommerce_after_shipping_rate

Comment: Спасибо Valerii Vasiliev